# Products do not show under category in Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce

I am building a site on top of Commerce Kickstart, no demo.
I created a category, but when creating a product of that content type it does not show under the category.
I do provide a menu link to the product but it still does not show.
I can see it from Manage Products.
What am I missing?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are creating Product Display node entries, not just product entries, correct?

Comment: I am a total noob to Commerce so don't quite understand your question. There is a new variation type, it is not product display, and it has its matching content type. So when I add a product I add from that content type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper steps for creating a new product type with matching product display (so you always have a 1:1 relationship of content type to product variation type.)

When making a variant it will ask to create a matching content type for the product display - which it sounds like you've opted for this.

On your created Product Display content type, make sure you add the existing Product Category term reference field. The Commerce Kickstart 2 catalog is very specific to its initial setup (demo or no demo, regardless.) It does some work to hijack the callback path for the provided taxonomy vocabulary.

In fact, for best results you should make sure the new content type mimics the default product display until you're familiar with how it all works.

Lastly, Commerce Kickstart 2 comes with the Inline Entity Form module. It is opinionated that products will always be created from the node form, not individually. So make sure you're creating nodes and populating the products through there.

Comment: I understand that I missed to add the Product Category term reference field. What I don't understand is how to create products from the node form, how do I create nodes and populate products through there?